# Rails Password Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passwords, pinterest

I'll start by telling you how I want my settings page set up.

I want users to be able to change their settings without requiring a password, and that's how it is set up now with this as the user model

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, :on => :create
validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, :on => :update, :unless => lambda{ |user| user.password.blank? }
```

This makes it so user's can change all of their settings without requiring a password (I know some might frown on this). But i want users to be able to change their passwords on the page like so...User clicks Change Password, a modal pops up, and users have to give their current password and then the new password and a confirmation of the new one. (I know how to do modal, i just want to know how do password reset).

Does this make sense?? I believe the way Pinterest does it is a good example (although they use Python I think)

Comment: Are you using devise?

Comment: No I made it from scratch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a form object:

**app/forms/change_password_form.rb**

```
class ChangePasswordForm
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  # Add all validations you need
  validates_presence_of :old_password, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validate :verify_old_password

  attr_accessor :old_password, :password, :password_confirmation

  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def submit(params)
    self.old_password = params[:old_pasword]
    self.password = params[:password]
    self.password_confirmation = params[:password_confirmation]

    if valid?
      @user.password = password
      @user.password_confirmation = password_confirmation
      @user.save!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def verify_old_password
    self.errors << "Not valid" if @user.password != password
  end

  # This method is required
  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

In controller initialize the form object `@pass_form = ChangePasswordForm.new(current_user)` and use the object in your modal: `form_for @pass_form...` and add the `old_password`, `password` and `password_confirmation` fields.

And finally, for example, in the update action:

```
@pass_form = ChangePasswordForm.new(current_user)

if @pass_form.submit(params[:change_password_form])
  redirect_to some_path
else
  render 'new'
end
```

I haven't tested this code, but you get the idea. Take a look to this [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects).

Comment: Do i need to add new columns to the user DB for this?

Comment: No, You are still using your `User` model. If you see `@user` is an instance of `User`.